# OSM: get residentials blocks, i.e. polygons enclosed by roads

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I'm trying to get a list of blocks / residential neighbourhoods via OSM. For many cities the whole town is tagged with a single `landuse=residential`. What I want is, for a given bounding box:

- get all landuse=residential areas
- "cut" them by roads
- return all found blocks as polygon

See for example this small town in Germany https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/49.96987/6.52802 and the attached image is the result I want (the red polygons; sorry my drawing is not completely accurate and not done for 100% of the image, but I hope my point is clear)

[image]

This could be achieved by overpass + custom code or a full import of the OSM database if necessary, i.e. no tech constraints from my side.

Comment: You will have to accept that a respective delineation cannot be 100% accurate, and requires manual post-processing and validation in any case; OSM road network data is exhaustively complex to work with, geometrically. The simplest approach would likely be to buffer the road(-lane) geometries by a realistic width (lane width *can* be part of the OSM tags; use a default value otherwise), union the results and calculate a geometric difference between it and the citywide landuse *Polygon*. Note that, depending on AOI size and road type inclusion this can easily take hours.